# How to remove Soap Security header

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm currently trying to consume a SOAP 1.2 web service using a WCF client. Problem is, whenever I make a request a `MessageSecurityException` with the following inner message is thrown:

```
SOAP header Security was not understood
```

From what I can tell, the WS does not understand the `Security` header, which is currently marked as `MustUnderstand="true"`.

How can I change `MustUnderstand`to false / remove the `Security` header?

Below is the binding I'm using right now:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="CteRecepcaoSoap12">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"/>
    <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: See the following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129358/need-help-with-manipulating-soap-header-in-my-wcf-client-before-sending-request

Comment: @WilliamXifaras I've tried using a custom inspector as the pointed out by you, unfortunately the 'Security' header doesn't seem to be removable (doesn't appear on the Headers collection of the Message). Maybe it's impossible after all.