# WCF Security Header Removal

Tags: c#, wcf, security, soap

I have read countless forum posts and articles on this issue and am still unable to find a solution.

I am running a WCF service with the following binding:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="BasicBinding">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Everything is working fine and I am locally able to make requests using the appropriate credentials and the response is served as expected. I have just received information from the consuming client that the Soap security header is causing issues for them:

```
   <s:Header>
     <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2017-12-20T19:17:29.322Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2017-12-20T19:22:29.322Z</u:Expires>
     </u:Timestamp>
  </o:Security>
```

They inform me that the 'mustunderstand' part is incompatible with their system. I have read that changing to a custom binding will fix it, however as you can see above this has been done and is still showing the security header.

I have read about interceptors and manipulating the response object but I've been unable to see how it all fits together. Has anyone actually solved this problem completely? I am basically looking to remove all header information from the response.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129358/need-help-with-manipulating-soap-header-in-my-wcf-client-before-sending-request) might set you in the right direction. I found configuring message inspectors to be challenging. If you're using Windsor and you register an `IEndpointBehavior`, it will get injected automatically without the other configuration.

Comment: Thanks Scott I will look into this. We have gone back to the client to find out if it is possible for the to deal with the issue on their end. It seems wrong for us to be changing our security mechanism just to suite one client. Alternatively I see that I could user Transport security on it's own with a user/pass solution which may not add that security header to the response.