# WCF Unable to Parse SOAP Envelop, Only Getting Default Values

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have created a WCF server for a callback service. A remote machine is suppose to call this service with a defined envelop format and try to accomplish a task.

I have the following SOAP Envelop to be parsed in a WCF Service:

```xml
<s:Envelope
  xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="e801930b-bf31-4509-b98a-96d106b5513f"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        
    </ActivityId>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <Delivery
      xmlns="http://hsbdserver/calcula/v1">
      <info
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Guid>5869a5c5-243e-11ed-4a4c-b14560d0fb70</Guid>
        <Name>Name</Name>
      </info>
      <items
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Item>
          <Guid>43207e16-906e-d94a-86f6-753ae31092ef</Guid>
          <Name>c37fb62f-2729-244b-a082-4be80d952c1e.txt</Name>
          <ExtDocId i:nil="true"/>
          <NewUserId i:nil="true"
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
          <NewUserName i:nil="true"
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <NewWorkflow>Done</NewWorkflow>
            <PreviousUserId
              xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
              <a:guid>0e67f61a-d1c6-c448-a11c-82ee8428028a</a:guid>
            </PreviousUserId>
            <PreviousUserName
              xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
              <a:string>Nick</a:string>
            </PreviousUserName>
            <PreviousWorkflow>Progress</PreviousWorkflow>
            <Code>xkde</Code>
          </Item>
        </items>
      </Delivery>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

The below is my C# implementation

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://hsbdserver/calcula/v1")]
public interface IServerCallback
{

  [OperationContract]
  void Delivery(Info info, Item[] items);
}


[DataContract]
public class Info
{
  Guid guid;
  string name;

  [DataMember]
  public Guid Guid
  {
    get { return guid; }
    set { guid = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
  }
}

[DataContract]
public class Item
{
  Guid guid;
  string name;
  string extDocId;
  Guid[] newAssignedUserId;
  string[] newUserId;
  Workflow newWorkflow;
  Guid[] previousUserId;
  string[] previousUserName;
  Workflow previousWorkflow;
  string code;

  [DataMember]
  public Guid Guid
  {
    get { return guid; }
    set { guid = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string ExtDocId
  {
    get { return extDocId; }
    set { extDocId = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public Guid[] NewAssignedUserId
  {
    get { return newAssignedUserId; }
    set { newAssignedUserId = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string[] NewUserId
  {
    get { return newUserId; }
    set { newUserId = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public Workflow NewWorkflow
  {
    get { return newWorkflow; }
    set { newWorkflow = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public Guid[] PreviousUserId
  {
    get { return previousUserId; }
    set { previousUserId = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string[] PreviousUserName
  {
    get { return previousUserName; }
    set { previousUserName = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public Workflow PreviousWorkflow
  {
    get { return previousWorkflow; }
    set { previousWorkflow = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string Code
  {
    get { return code; }
    set { code = value; }
  }
}

public enum Workflow
{
  Progress,
  Done
}
```

However the service is unable to interpret the SOAP envelop. I have a breakpoint at the beginning of `Deliver` method, it gets hit however the values seem default ones. For example GUIDs are just a bunch of zeros and the `items` array is empty as well.

What am I missing here? How should I make the C# class to reflect the SOAP envelop?

Comment: You can take a look at [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129358/need-help-with-manipulating-soap-header-in-my-wcf-client-before-sending-request).

Answer (score -1):

Here are the classes for deserialize which should be the same for SOAP

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics")]
        public ActivityId ActivityId { get; set; }
    }
    public class ActivityId
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://hsbdserver/calcula/v1")]
        public Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
    }
    public class Delivery
    {
        public Info info { get; set; }
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "items")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Item")]
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Info
    {
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ExtDocId { get; set; }
        public string NewUserId { get; set; }
        public string NewUserName { get; set; } 
        public string NewWorkflow { get; set; }
        public PreviousUserId PreviousUserId { get; set; }
        public PreviousUserName PreviousUserName { get; set; }
        public string PreviousWorkflow { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
    public class PreviousUserId
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "guid", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
        public string Guid { get; set; }
    }
    public class PreviousUserName
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "string", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this compatible with WCF? Is there a way to generate WCF contact instead of XML parser?

Comment: Everything is the same except the WCF starts inside the body.  So Envelope, Header, and Body class is not needed.  An the attributes (above the properties) need to be changed.  The important thing is the namespaces are the same.  You are missing the namespaces. You also have arrays and the xml do not have arrays on items.

Comment: So how can I define `Delivery()` using your example. Currently in my concrete implementation of `IServerCallback` which is known as `ServerCallback.svc` I just have the following method signature `public void Delivery(Info info, Item[] items)`. Will this work if I have the classes like you mentioned?

Comment: Also I would like to know if there is a way to bypass or ignore the namespace validation?

Comment: Namespaces cannot be ignored.  Array s are tricky since they are case sensitive (upper,lower) and default to two xml tags.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts?force_isolation=true